# date.getDay is not a functionと出てしまいました

Tags: javascript

カレンダーの元データはこちらから取得しました。
https://github.com/MathiasWP/CalendarPickerJS/

`date.getDay()` の部分で以下のエラーが出ます。
特定の曜日の時にあるCSSを適応させたいです。

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: date.getDay is not a function
    at CalendarPicker.js:278
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at CalendarPicker._insertDaysIntoGrid (Ca.js:263)
    at new CalendarPicker (Ca.js:96)
    at a:137
(anonymous) @ a:278
CalendarPicker._insertDaysIntoGrid @:263
CalendarPicker a
(anonymous) @ a:137
```

**ソースコード:**

```
CalendarPicker.prototype._insertDaysIntoGrid = function () {
    this.calendarGrid.innerHTML = '';

    var arrayOfDays = this._getDaysInMonth(this.month, this.year);
    var firstDayOfMonth = arrayOfDays[0].getDay();

    // Converting Sunday (0 when using getDay()) to 7 to make it easier to work with.
    firstDayOfMonth = firstDayOfMonth === 0 ? 7 : firstDayOfMonth;

    if (1 < firstDayOfMonth) {
        arrayOfDays = Array(firstDayOfMonth - 1).fill(false, 0).concat(arrayOfDays);
    }

    arrayOfDays.forEach(date => {
        var dateElement = document.createElement(date ? this.calendarDayElementType : 'span');
        var Date = date.toString().split(' ')[2];

        var dateIsTheCurrentValue = this.value.toString() === date.toString();
        if (dateIsTheCurrentValue) this.activeDateElement = dateElement;

        var dateIsBetweenAllowedRange = (this.min || this.max) && (date.toString() !== this.today.toString() && (date < this.min || date > this.max))
        if (dateIsBetweenAllowedRange) {
            dateElement.classList.add('disabled');
        } else {
            dateElement.tabIndex = 0;
            dateElement.value = date;
        }
        if(date.getDay() == 5)
        {
            dateElement.classList.add('friday');
        }

        dateElement.textContent = date ? Date : '';
        this.calendarGrid.appendChild(dateElement);
    })
```

Comment: this._getDaysInMonth() の戻り値が Date の配列ではないのでしょう。現状のコードだけだとそれしかわかりません。

Comment: おっと、見落としているところがありました。回答を書いてみます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    arrayOfDays = Array(firstDayOfMonth - 1).fill(false, 0).concat(arrayOfDays);
```

ここで、`arrayOfDays`の先頭に firstDayOfMonth-1 個の `false` を入れています。なので、`arrayOfDays` はおそらく `false` か `Date` オブジェクトのどちらかの配列なのでしょう。
`false`の場合は`getDay()`は呼べないので、`if (date && date.getDay() == 5)` とすれば動くのではないでしょうか。